# LayoutInflater not updating the TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an application that has a navigation drawer and where the user is required to login.

So far, I've got the whole user login/registration thing working and I've built the navigation drawer.

What I want to do now is to make the TextViews on the navigation drawer display the user's full name and his/her email.

I've tried to do so with the LayoutInflater, but the TextViews don't change.

I've also tried passing the user information to LogCat and it displays it correctly.

I don't know where my problem is.

Here is my code:

**DrawerActivity.java**

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    public static String[] userInfo = LoginActivity.userInfo;
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.navDrawerTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout);

        //Declare instances.
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View drawerHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
        TextView tvFullName = (TextView) drawerHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView tvEmail = (TextView) drawerHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        ImageView imgProfile = (ImageView) drawerHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);

        tvFullName.setText(userInfo[0] + " " + userInfo[1]);
        tvEmail.setText(userInfo[2]);
        Log.d("First name", "First name: " + userInfo[0]);
        Log.d("Last name", "Last name: " + userInfo[1]);
        Log.d("Email", "Email: " + userInfo[2]);
...
```

**EDIT**

**drawer_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="#444444">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/userInfoWrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_face_white_48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**EDIT 2**

**activity_drawer_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Activity Content-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigationDrawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_width="270dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawer_header"
        layout="@layout/drawer_header" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="#444444"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please show your xml there is no need of LayoutInflater if you already have fields in layout

Comment: Check that your Textviews are actually being set, and / or post your xml!

Comment: then you want to add this headerview run time or you already included in menu show your activity_drawer_layout and menu layout

Comment: @dave I posted the layout file in the edit.

Comment: @Pavan I tried doing what Losin' Me suggested (mNavigationDrawer.addView(drawerHeaderView)), but it didn't change anything sadly.

Comment: thats why i asking for your menu and the activity_drawer_layout to check real scenario which you trying

Comment: @Pavan check the second edit.

Comment: @UltraAlkaline check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need to use LayoutInflater, simply try this and let me know

```
TextView tvFullName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
TextView tvEmail = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
ImageView imgProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);

tvFullName.setText(userInfo[0] + " " + userInfo[1]);
tvEmail.setText(userInfo[2]);
```

for your clarification it worked because it is already defined in a layout so you can access it directly. LayoutInflater is used in case you want to add some views runtime using defined layout.

Comment: yeh also understand why it worked just updated answer with description

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling

`drawerHeaderView.invalidate();`

after setting the text to refresh the views, since the layout has already been inflated.

I'm probably wrong but it could potentially be an issue with the way you are getting an instance of LayoutInflater. Try

`LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly, none of the ways that you stated worked.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the inflated view to a parent view like this:

```
RelativeLayout userInfoRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.userInfoWrapper);
userInfoRL.addView(drawerHeaderView);
//just in case use the userInfoRL.invalidate();
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: and what is your answer says adding same view to itself

Comment: It does work, but it also adds another CircleImageView. I'm guessing because it's adding the whole view to itself. Where do I go from here?